# Is every retraction homotopic to a smooth retraction?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am not an expert in Differential Topology, so let me apologize if this question admits a straightforward answer. I checked some standard references, but I could not find one.

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold with boundary $N:= \partial M$, and assume that there exists a *continuous* retraction of $M$ onto $N$, namely, a continuous map $r \colon M \to N$ that is the identity on $N$.

> **Question.** Does there exist a *smooth* retraction $s \colon M \to N$? And what about a smooth retraction homotopic to $r$?

I am aware that, by Whitney Approximation Theorem, $r \colon M \to N$ is homotopic to a smooth map, but I do not see how to conclude from this that it is homotopic to a smooth retraction.

**Motivation.** This question arose when I was trying to mimic the standard proof of Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem (for *continuous* maps $f \colon \mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{D}^n$) by using de Rham cohomology, instead of singular homology. In the homology setting, the starting point is the non-existence of a continuous retraction $r \colon \mathbb{D}^n \to S^{n-1}$, which is obtained by contradiction looking at the functorial group homomorphisms induced by $r$ and by the inclusion $i \colon S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{D}^n$. But de Rham cohomology is only functorial with respect to *smooth* maps...

Comment: There is a relative version of the approximation result you mentioned: any continuous map $f\colon M\rightarrow M'$ that is smooth on some closed subset $A\subset M$ is homotopic to a smooth map via a homotopy that is constant on $A$.

Comment: by "that is constant on $A$" did you mean "that is the identity on $A$?" Or "that coincides with $f$ on $A$?"

Comment: The latter. This should be in Hirsch’ for example

Comment: If you want to prove Brouwer using de Rham cohomology, it is easier to first prove it for smooth functions (which avoids the subtlety you pointed out), and then derive it for continuous functions by approximating them by smooth ones (easier since you don’t need to preserve being a retraction).

Comment: @AndyPutman: thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate a bit on your method? By Whitney approximation, I know that a continuous function $f  \colon \mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{D}^n$ is homotopic to a smooth function $g \colon  \mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{D}^n$. If $$H(x, t) \colon \mathbb{D}^n \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{D}^n$$ is the homotopy, with $H(x, \, 0)=g$ and $H(x, \, 1)=f$, may I assume that $H_t(x):=H(x, \, t)$ is smooth for all $t <1$? And, even so, how can I deduce the existence of a fixed point for $f$ from the existence of a fixed point for $H_t$ for all $0 \leq t <1$?

Comment: I presume that some sequence $x_{t_n}$ of fixed points for $H_{t_n}$ will converge to a fixed point $x_0$ of $H_0=f$. But, in general, the fixed points of $H_{t_n}$ are not unique, so I do not see a "canonical" way to choose one and construct my sequence. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi the proof of Brower's theorem by approximation is a slightly more complicated than that,  see pg.14-15 of Milnor. Topology from a differentiable viewpoint. University Press of Virginia. 1965.

Comment: The argument in Milnor’s book is what I had in mind.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much to everyone. I will look at Milnor's argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a collar of the boundary we resort to the case when $r\in C^0(M, \partial M)$ is given by the projection $\partial M\times I \to \partial M$ over the collar .

Since $r$ is smooth on an open neighbourhood of $\partial M$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a smooth $g\in C^\infty(M,\partial M)$ such that $g=r$ in a neighbourhood of $\partial M$ and $|g-r|<\epsilon$.

For a reference  see Prop. 3.11 of Milnor's lectures on Differential Topology 1958  (notes taken by James Munkres).